# How to get value from JSON object in c#? If the key is not defined

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Below is my JSON information where you can notice that there is not any key defined.

```
{"KOA": {"test.jpg": "xyz.com/images/test.jpg"}}
```

I am Looking the Output like:

```
string _imgName=  ms-koa-acazia-ceramic.jpg
string _imgUrl= xyz.com/images/test.jpg
```

"KOA" is also a dynamic value it can be changed so I can not fix it.

Comment: What do you mean by '"KOA"` is a dynamic value? Do you mean `KOA` will not always be referred to by that name or that the underlying properties will change?

Comment: KOA will not always be referred to by that name...

Comment: You should really look into how `JSON` is formatted a little more. Your current `JSON` is not even `JSON` really. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach you can use to achieve this is to use dictionaries to deserialize the JSON object

```
        const string jsonString = "{\"KOA\": { \"test.jpg\": \"xyz.com / images / test.jpg\"}}";
        var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, IDictionary<string, string>>>(jsonString);

        string firstKey = jsonObject.Keys.First();

        string _imgName = jsonObject[firstKey].Keys.First();
        string _imgUrl = jsonObject[firstKey].Values.First();
```

Comment: IN case of multiple pair how can we get the value {"KOA": 
{"xyz.jpg":
 "xyz.com/sigaro-ivory-essentials-ceramic-a.jpg",
  "abc.jpg":
   "abc/sigaro-ivory-essentials-ceramic-b.jpg"}}

Comment: in this case, I would use the JObjet class first to obtain the value of KOA, and then I would use a dictionary to get the other values

Comment: const string jsonString = "{\"KOA\": { \"xyz.jpg\": \"xyz.com/sigaro-ivory-essentials-ceramic-a.jpg\", \"abc.jpg\": \"abc/sigaro-ivory-essentials-ceramic-b.jpg\"}}";

            var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(jsonString);

            var koaName = jsonObject.First.Path;
            var koaValue = jsonObject[koaName].Value<JObject>();

            var values = koaValue.ToObject<Dictionary<string, string>>();